# Does the following limit exist and if it exists, what is the answer?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the limit of $\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)}$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1848836/201168).

Comment: @Isha Dhiman: This question has been asked here before. Did you perform any search before posting this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Verify the inequality

$\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le |x|$

Answer (score 0):

For $x=0$ you have $f(0,y) = \frac {0y^2}{0+y^2} = 0$,
and for $y=kx$ it is $f(x,y) = \frac {k^2x^3}{(1+k^2)x^2} = \frac {k^2}{1+k^2}x$.

What are possible values of $\frac {k^2}{1+k^2}$...?
And what are possible values of $x$ inside a circle of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$...?